# Python Program - program to find largest sequence in a given list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sequence

I need to design a python program which outputs the largest sequence in a given list of numbers.

For example,

```
INPUT = [1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6]
```

Expected Result:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Can someone please help me with the code?

Comment: Hello @Sociopath, can you please help me how to code this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

new_l = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda ix : ix[0] - ix[1]):
    new_l.append(list(map(itemgetter(1), g)))

print(max(new_l, key=lambda x: len(x)))
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank You @Sociopath, code runs successful and outputs as expected.

Comment: @SNS Your TA will jump on their  seat from pleasure when they'll see this very nice code!

Answer (score 1):

An approach without using in-built python modules and with code complexity of O(n)

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6]

large_seq = []
large_seq_len = 0
temp_seq = []
temp_seq_len = 0
x = None

for i in a:
    if x is None or x + 1 == i:
        temp_seq.append(i)
        temp_seq_len += 1
    else:
        if temp_seq_len > large_seq_len:
            large_seq = temp_seq
            large_seq_len = temp_seq_len
        temp_seq = [i]
        temp_seq_len = 1
    x = i

if temp_seq_len > large_seq_len:
    large_seq = temp_seq

print(large_seq)
```

https://www.online-python.com/XNjaLm9vMS

Comment: Of course your method is the sensible way to go… +1

Answer (score 1):

[Sociopath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60966826/2749397) can be folded into a relatively short one-liner

```
$ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  7 2020, 21:25:33) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from itertools import groupby as g
>>> d, e, l, λ, m = [1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6], enumerate, len, list, max
>>> [i[1]for i in m((λ(s)for k,s in g(e(d),lambda j:j[0]-j[1])),key=lambda j:l(j))]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```